# Removing duplicate songs in an Apple Music playlist

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, apple-music

Is there any way to remove duplicate songs from an Apple Music playlist that I have? I imported two similar playlists from other users into a single playlist on my account.

I did some searching, but nothing has come up.

Note that I am asking about Apple Music playlists, and not local iTunes playlists.

Answer (score 1):

The best and most comprehensive automation source for iTunes is Doug’s scripts.

- https://dougscripts.com/itunes/index.php

I would guess this is a pre-made script for this as is, and if not, you would probably have to use the duplicate finder you want and filter the input to only be playlists. You would need to sign in to your Apple Music on a Mac long enough to run that script of course. I’m guessing someone could make a Workflow automation that only runs on iOS but I havent come across some example of that yet. Maybe this jogs someone’s memory about a ready-to-run script in workflow app.

- Workflow by Apple https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workflow/id915249334?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try app [Playlist tools](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/playlist-tools/id1484222423). Finds duplicate songs and creates a new playlist without duplicates. Then you can delete the original playlist.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  Also, thank you for your answer. I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your answer, if you're affiliated in some way with the site you're linking to, please disclose this in your answer, otherwise it may get flagged as SPAM.